# Why does an unordered list leave a blank item at the start with CSS column-count?

Tags: css, html-lists, css-multicolumn-layout

I have an unordered list which I want split into columns, so I'm using CSS `column-count` on the parent div:

```html
<h1>Mushrooms:</h1>
<div style="column-count:4">
  <ul>
    <li>Porcini</li>
    <li>Shittake</li>
    <li>Button</li>
    <li>Chestnut</li>
    <li>Oyster</li>
    <li>Portobello</li>
    <li>Crimino</li>
    <li>Chanterelle</li>
    <li>Morels</li>
    <li>Enoki</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, for some reason this leaves a blank line in the first row of the first column:

[image]

How do I get my columns neat and tidy?

There is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrwLnb43/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UL has a margin-top that causes the space. Set the margin-top on 0 on the UL and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

make margin 0px for the ul,because browsers have default value for the ul

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `div` here to use `column-count`, you can apply directly to `ul` (also don't forget the vendor prefix)

besides `margin` (which my solve your issue) `ul` also have by default `padding` which you might want to reset.

Note: avoid use inline styles.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
ul {
  margin: 0 0 36px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4
}
```

```html
<h1>Mushrooms:</h1>
<ul>
  <li>Porcini</li>
  <li>Shittake</li>
  <li>Button</li>
  <li>Chestnut</li>
  <li>Oyster</li>
  <li>Portobello</li>
  <li>Crimino</li>
  <li>Chanterelle</li>
  <li>Morels</li>
  <li>Enoki</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not working well, the bullets are on the left and not in every column. Chrome OS X 51.0.2704.79 (64-bit)

Comment: which browser?? here is exactly as the OP using FF